# QGIS Georeferencer: How to deal with .points file using different CRSs?

Tags: qgis, coordinate-system, georeferencing, ground-control

I have some scanned maps as tifs and their corresponding .points files. The GCPs were set by different users erroneously using different CRSs. E.g. Of 340 points 180 were set using EPSG:23700, 160 were set in EPSG:3857.

Now with this large amount of GCPs in different CRS QGIS just freezes. Even when using a smaller number, say 20 points with different CRSs, the transformation process is significantly slower.

In order to correct the error I add the *.points file as delimited text layer without geometry, then loading it as virtual layer via DB-Manager using the following query:

```
select
st_x(geometry)as mapX,
st_y(geometry)as mapY,
pixelX, pixelY, enable, dX, dY, residual
from(
    select
    case when mapX < 500000 then
    st_transform(st_geomfromtext('POINT('||mapX||' '||mapY||')',23700),3857)
    else 
    st_geomfromtext('POINT('||mapX||' '||mapY||')',3857)
    end
    as geometry,* from GCP-points-file
)
```

and exporting the result as csv with the extension .points.

Is there a way to do this more streamlined?

I am dealing with a bunch of these multi-CRS GCPs.

I forgot to mention that this approach comes with a huge usability problem:

After loading the new points file, GCPs are toggled invisible - assumingly because they don't correspond with the new mapX and mapY values anymore or they are set to 0.
This means I have to click 340 times to set each GCP to visible so that dX, dY and Residual is recalculated.

Comment: Your solution feels pretty good to me. Not even using GDAL virtual format would help you because the GCPList has one common Projection for all the ground control points https://gdal.org/drivers/raster/vrt.html.

Comment: I believe that the visibility is set with a field in the points file. Perhaps your code does not set right value to the field.